# Поменять версию php

Tags: php, windows, cmd, wamp

Здравствуйте, у меня windows 10, установил wamp, до этого был openserver.

Когда в cmd пишу `php -v` выводится версия **PHP 5.5.13 (cli)**, на wammp стоит php 5.6.25, **как мне поставить чтобы из командной строки запускался php из wamp?**

В переменнах среды стоит php от wamp
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменной path добавить путь к php7 и убрать путь к php5.

Comment: я перепутал, не php7 а php 5.6.25, в cmd всё равно показывается PHP 5.5.13 (cli)

Comment: В переменной path добавьте путь, который у вас к php прописан. А тот что ведет к 5.5.13 - удалите оттуда.